# How do I disallow cin from forwarding to the next input if I enter more than one word per cin?

Tags: c++

On each input of this program, I want the user to be able to type in however many "words" (meaning text separated by spaces/tabs) they desire...but to disallow the user from being able to input words beyond the current cin. For example: if I type John Smith Doe, I want John to be put into 'name', and Smith and Doe to be discarded.  Then I want to enter the 'age' and 'weight' without having Smith going to age and Doe going to weight.  Currently, if I input John Doe for the name, then age becomes Doe.  If I enter John Smith Doe for the name, then age becomes Smith and weight becomes Doe.
Can anyone help with this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    string name;
    string age;
    string weight;

    //user can enter more than one name (title, first, middle, last, etc.)
    cout << "Enter your name: " << endl;
    cin >> name;

    //if user entered two or more names above,
    //disallow cin from putting name two into 'age'
    cout << "Enter your age: " << endl;
    cin >> age;

    //same thing for weight
    cout << "Enter your weight: " << endl;
    cin >> weight;

    cout << "You typed: " << endl;
    cout << "Name: " << name << endl;
    cout << "Age: " << age << endl;
    cout << "Weight: " << weight << "." << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You want std::getline(stream, string)

Comment: You simply [ignore](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore) it.

Comment: How, when your code prompted for name, did your code skip the 'title' input?  Why do your comments use 'first', 'middle', 'last' instead of 'name'?  Perhaps your prompt is inadequate.  Can you improve your requirement statement?

Comment: This was the best answer...specifically: getline(stream, string).

Answer (score 1):

I think you can just use

```
std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

for example after `cin >> name;`.

Comment: Along those lines, but a bit more standard-ese `cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max())`

Comment: This will skip a line, if a new-line character follows the 'name'

Comment: @DieterLücking, you are right. I will edit my answer

Answer (score 0):

Read the stream line by line, pass each line to a istingstream and read the fields of interest:

```
// Read Fields [Teminating State]
inline std::istream& read_fields(std::istringstream& line_stream)
{
    return line_stream;
}

// Read Fields
template <typename Arg, typename ... Args>
inline std::istream& read_fields(std::istringstream& line_stream, Arg& arg, Args&... args)
{
    if(line_stream >> arg)
        read_fields(line_stream, args...);
    return line_stream;
}

// Read and Skip Fields of a Line
template <typename ... Args>
std::istream& read_line(std::istream& stream, Args& ... args)
{
    std::string line;
    if(std::getline(stream, line)) {
        std::istringstream line_stream(line);
        read_fields(line_stream, args...);
        if(line_stream.fail()) {
            // Pass the fail state to the stream.
            stream.setstate(std::ios_base::failbit);
        }
    }
    return stream;
}

// Test
int main()
{
    std::string name;
    read_line(std::cin, name);

    std::string age;
    std::string weight;
    read_line(std::cin, age, weight);

    if(std::cin)
        std::cout << "Name: " << name << ", Age: " << age << "Weight: " << weight << '\n';
    else
        std::cout << "Failure\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I developed.  Thank you for your help!

```
string name;
string age;
string weight;

cout << "Enter your name: " << endl;
//this line allows me to take in a full line (up
//to the newline character) at once
getline(cin, name);
//then i search for the first occurence of a 
//spacebar, or output the whole line if none
//is found
int i = 0;
int len = name.length();
for(; i < len; i++)
{
    if(name[i] == ' ')
    {
        break;
    }
}
//chop off end of variable 'name'
//after first spacebar or leave 
//it whole if no spacebar was
//found
name = name.substr(0, i);

//same thing as above for here
cout << "Enter your age: " << endl;
getline(cin, age);
i = 0;
len = age.length();
for(; i < len; i++)
{
    if(age[i] == ' ')
    {
        break;
    }
}
age = age.substr(0, i);

//ditto for here
cout << "Enter your weight: " << endl;
getline(cin, weight);
i = 0;
len = weight.length();
for(; i < len; i++)
{
    if(weight[i] == ' ')
    {
        break;
    }
}
weight = weight.substr(0, i);

cout << "You typed: " << endl;
cout << "Name: " << name << endl;
cout << "Age: " << age << endl;
cout << "Weight: " << weight << endl;
```